# RegEx for splitting SQL queries in a text file

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I have the following SQL file:

```
  CREATE TABLE TABLE1
   (    ID INTEGER, 
   );
   
  CREATE TABLE TABLE2
   (    ID INTEGER,
```

I want to extract the queries. I do this with the following code:

```
try {
    Path sqlPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:/Users/myPC/Desktop/create_tables.sql");
    String sql = new String(Files.readAllBytes(sqlPath));
    commands = sql.split("\n\n");
    System.out.println(commands.length) //== 1 while it should be 2;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return;
}
```

But I get:

> parsing exception expected EOF or CREATE, ...

What should be the regex delimiter in this case?

Comment: Do you get the exception in the line where you use split?

Comment: I guess you should use the following regex pattern inyour split function:
commands = sql.split(";\\s*");

Comment: No the exception in a related code but `commands.length` is returning 1 and not 2

Comment: have you tried this: commands = sql.split(";\\s*");

Comment: @marcnicole The regex inside the split command is actually correct. I tried to put the contents into a string directly instead of loading from a file and it was splitting as expected. May be the issue is with reading the file. Did you try printing out the content of `sql` string ?

Comment: or this: commands = sql.split("(?<=;)\\s*");
if you want to keep the semicolon

Comment: maybe it does read the bytes with the wrong encoding

Comment: try System.out.println(sql);

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String[] commands = sql.split("(?<=;)\\s+");
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/lM6iVX/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

Comment: I would use \\s* since you don't know if the code is actually formatted and containes any spaces after the semicolon

Comment: @IntoVoid The input strings contain whitespace.

Comment: yeah sure, but I thought that the input might change. depending on the data base